how to add array data in single field in CockroachDB
Here is the payload and need to insert payload.b data individually
payload = {
a:test1,
b: [1,2,3,4]
}
expecting out in table db
test1 1
test1 2
test1 3
test1 4
i tried using unset query shown below
query = INSERT INTO "store" ("userId", "eventTypeId") SELECT ${payload.userId} AS "userId", unnest(${payload.eventTypeIds}) AS "eventTypeId"

Please [edit] your post for correct formatting

I was able to perform an INSERT of the same data layout (JSON with these fields) by using a CTE. See below:
WITH payload AS (
    SELECT 
    '{"a": "test1", "b": [1,2,3,4]}'::jsonb as data
)
INSERT INTO store (userId, eventTypeId)
SELECT 
    data->>'a',
    (jsonb_array_elements(data->'b'))::text::integer
FROM payload;
...
INSERT 0 4

Time: 10ms total (execution 9ms / network 1ms)

As you can see above, it does require an explicit cast to JSONB first to get the payload field. Then it selects the data's "a" and "b" fields and casts appropriately to get the format expected in the store table
